# reprogramming a key for 2006 chevy malibu

Tags: chevrolet, key, malibu

i changed the master key for my 2006 chevy malibu because the old key got lost. now i have lost the new key and found the old one. is there a way to reprogram the key to work again? Will the instructions for programming a blank key work for this as well?

Answer (score 1):

Try this, put the key in and leave it in the run position for half an hour. This should learn the key to the anti theft system. You may also want to hook up a battery charger.

If that fails a scan tool will be required.

Comment: do you know what the scan tool is called?

Comment: @Michelle You'd probably need a Tech 2. Though it may be cheaper just to have your car towed to a dealer and have them do it.